# Problem with List of Symbols

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries

Hello fellows and folks!

I am having trouble when trying to put a redefined symbol: `\newcommand{\MatrixVariable}[1]{\bm{\mathit{#1}}}` in the list of symbols. Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

This is the actual code I'm using in the preamble, except the `\documentclass{report}` etc.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long]

\chapter{Sample}
Reference symbols: $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, $\gls{a}$, $\gls{t}$,
$\gls{F}$.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your *picture*, I’d guess that you forgot to load the `bm` package and the “Undefined control sequence” message was referring to the unknown `\bm` command. (This is why you should prepare a minimal example which *replicates* your problem, not just a picture, because your code spinet complies fine.)

Try

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=none]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{bm}% Is this package missing in your source file?
\newcommand{\MatrixVariable}[1]{\bm{#1}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Rating Matrix}]{MatrixVariable{R}}{\ensuremath{\MatrixVariable{R}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long]

\chapter{Sample}
Reference symbols: $\gls{MatrixVariable{R}}$

\end{document}
```

Note that I’ve removed the inner `\mathit`—this is not needed (in fact it switches to text italic in math mode)—using `\bm{#1}` suffices.